# 20.04 - chmod not working on exfat mount

Tags: server, permissions, samba, fstab, chmod

I have 2 internal HDDs formatted in exFAT - fstab as below

```
#INT-1TB-4K Internal HDD mount to /mnt/INT-1TB-4K
UUID=0E7E-6579 /mnt/INT-1TB-4K exfat defaults, permissions 0 0

#INT-1TB-BAK Internal HDD mount to /mnt/INT-1TB-BAK
UUID=3037-96B0 /mnt/INT-1TB-BAK exfat defaults, permissions 0 0
```

Running Ubuntu Server 20.04, for which kernel supports exFAT without the exfat-utils / fuse packages being present.

/mnt ls-all gives

```
exharris@plexserv:/mnt$ ls -all
total 520
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jul  2 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4096 Jul  2 05:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 262144 Jul  3 03:49 INT-1TB-4K
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 262144 Jul  3 03:49 INT-1TB-BAK
```

I get permission denied errors in the terminal when trying to create files in these folders (unless I use 'sudo', of course). This is because the 'others' write bit is set to -.

When running `sudo chmod -R 777 INT-1TB-4K` from /mnt, I get no errors, but when doing ls -all again, nothing has changed.

This is causing me problems also as I have set these up as Samba shares and also cannot write to them from other machines.

I also tried `sudo chmod -R o+w INT-1TB-4K` - same thing happened.

Comment: Caveat: I say this without authoritative knowledge. But I think exfat volumes don't suppport this properly? To make this work reliably I had to change the format to ntfs. ext4 would likely work as well, but I needed this disk to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 10):

And what happens when you do this:

** Unmount the partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/INT-1TB-4K
```

** Change your mount expressions to this:

```
UUID=0E7E-6579 /mnt/INT-1TB-4K exfat defaults,umask=000 0 0
```

** Make systemd happy:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Remount with this:

```
sudo mount -a
```

ExFAT should have mounted 777 by default so I'm guessing your use of the "permissions" option disrupted the space-time continuum.

Hind-site is 20/20 but NTFS would have been a better choice - if you were going to use a non-linux-native filesystem.

Comment: thanks - fixed my issue. :)

Comment: The mount expression also fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All you should need to do is mount the drive with the `umask=0000` option (which is equivalent to `chmod 777`). Since exFAT doesn't have permissions like ext4 or NTFS does, the mask permissions apply disk-wide. Use `fmask` for files and `dmask` for directories if you need to make that distinction.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/external -o umask=0000
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me

Comment: This worked for me too! Do you know how to translate this in fstab for auto mounting?